# Change opacity using leaflet without plugin

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, json

I have a geojson and try change the opacity chaging the button, but it dont work anyway.

Where statesData is my geojson.js, style and onEachFeacture are others functions that I have.

Here is my button:

```
<span id="image-opacity">0.5</span>
<input type="range" id="sldOpacity" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="0.5" />
```

And here is my JS

```
$('#sldOpacity').on('change', function(){
  $('#image-opacity').html(this.value);
  geojson.setOpacity(this.value);
});

var geojson = L.geoJson(statesData, {
        style: style,
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    }).addTo(map);
```

I tried put opacity: opacity and create a function opacity() but dont work too. What I have do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the `geojson` variable first, then listen for slider `change` event. Furthermore, `setOpacity` is not a function for geojson layers. You should use `setStyle`:

```
var geojson = L.geoJson(statesData, {
        style: style,
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    }).addTo(map);

$('#sldOpacity').on('change', function(){
    $('#image-opacity').html(this.value);
    geojson.setStyle({opacity: this.value, fillOpacity: this.value});
});
```

Comment: I tried it, but dont work too :( return this: Uncaught TypeError: geojson.setOpacity is not a function

Comment: Typeof in geojson return object

Comment: Ok, I've just updated the answer to solve the issue.