# Changing opacity for KML layer fetched in Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, javascript, kml

Is it possible to change the opacity for the .kml file, that has been attached via leaflet-plugin?

Basically the plugin is here:

https://github.com/windycom/leaflet-kml

but after implementation into the Leaflet we have a full opaque image. It's fine for placemarks, but how about the icons/images included, which cover some box on the map?

My code looks like this:

```
var kml = fetch('Coventry.kml')
      .then( res => res.text() )
      .then( kmltext => {

            // Create new kml overlay
            parser = new DOMParser();
            kml = parser.parseFromString(kmltext,"text/xml");

            console.log(kml)

            const track = new L.KML(kml)
            map.addLayer(track)
            // Adjust map to show the kml
            const bounds = track.getBounds()
            map.fitBounds( bounds )
      }).setOpacity(0.6).addTo(map)

      $('#sldOpacity').on('change', function(){
$('#image-opacity').html(this.value);
kml.setStyle({opacity: this.value, fillOpacity: this.value});
 });
```

whereas to the pure code straight from the leaflet-kml example I added up sth like:
      .setOpacity(0.6).addTo(map)

but isn't working.

The console states, that:

Uncaught TypeError: fetch(...).then(...).then(...).setOpacity is not a function
    at (index):143

I was also trying this example:

[Change opacity using leaflet without plugin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261668/change-opacity-using-leaflet-without-plugin)

but it didn't help me unfortunately

In the L.KML.js file I found a snip:

```
 var value = e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                if (key === 'color') {
                    options.opacity = parseInt(value.substring(50, 50), 16) / 255.0;
                    options.color = '#' + value.substring(6, 8) + 
value.substring(4, 6) + value.substring(2, 4);
                } else if (key === 'width') {,
```

where in `value.substring` I put 50 instead of 0. No result at all.

Is it some way to make this .kml layer more transparent?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like I found a decent solution to make it:

First of all, the good code is provided by:

https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins

where is the .kml section.

You must copy the KML.js file into your repository

Then in the front script code use:

```
  var track = new L.KML('Coventry.kml', {async: true})
    .on('loaded', function (e) {
        map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
    })
    .addTo(map);
L.control.layers({}, {'Track':track}).addTo(map);
```

without any opacity settings in Javascript, because this plugin recognizes an Image opacity properties set in the .XML code:

```
 <GroundOverlay>
<name>Coventry.tif</name>
<description>http://localhost/testc/Coventry.tif</description>
<Icon>
    <href>https://i.imgur.com/58CbNhB.png</href>
    <viewBoundScale>0.75</viewBoundScale>
</Icon>
<color>55ffffff</color>
<LatLonBox>
    <north>52.39388512224325</north>
    <south>52.39299906007814</south>
    <east>-1.458241039649089</east>
    <west>-1.460061203494303</west>
</LatLonBox>
 </GroundOverlay>
 <GroundOverlay>
<name>Coventry2.tif</name>
<description>http://localhost/testc/Coventry.tif2</description>
<Icon>
    <href>https://i.imgur.com/58CbNhB.png</href>
    <viewBoundScale>0.75</viewBoundScale>
    <color>00ff6633</color>
</Icon>
<color>99ffffff</color>
<LatLonBox>
    <north>52.39299906007814</north>
    <south>52.39199906007814</south>
    <east>-1.458241039649089</east>
    <west>-1.460061203494303</west>
</LatLonBox>
</GroundOverlay>
```

This solution canb be applicable for Icons (External URL images) fetched by .kml file like

```
<Icon>
    <href>https://i.imgur.com/58CbNhB.png</href>
</Icon>
```

Unlike for the solution proposed above, that works easier for KML polygon transparency instead of icon included.

In the result your KML layer will loke as per in the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You mixed a few things here. `kml` is XML object, not a Leaflet layer, so you cannot set opacity to it with `setOpacity` function or add it to the map.

Leaflet layer that comes from kml and you are interested in is `track`. This is feature group layer for which you can set style with `setStyle` method. You have to declare it outside `fetch`, so it be available later to change it's opacity with slider.

Your code could then look something like this:

```
var track;

var kml = fetch('Coventry.kml')
  .then( res => res.text() )
  .then( kmltext => {
        parser = new DOMParser();
        kml = parser.parseFromString(kmltext,"text/xml");
        track = new L.KML(kml);
        map.addLayer(track);
        const bounds = track.getBounds();
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });

$('#sldOpacity').on('change', function(){
  $('#image-opacity').html(this.value);
  track.setStyle({opacity: this.value, fillOpacity: this.value});
 });
```

**EDIT:** In your JSFiddle code you are using JQuery without link to library and you are using slider code without required HTML elements. Here is working JSFiddle (KML is defined in code): https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/7nxfgtu8/

Here is the main part of the code:

```
<body>
<div id="mapid"></div>
<div>
  <span id="image-opacity">0.5</span>
  <input type="range" id="sldOpacity" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="0.5" />
</div>
<script>
var myKML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' +
  '<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"> ' +
  '<Document> ' +
    '<name>polygon.kml</name> ' +
    '<Style id="transYellowPoly"> ' +
      '<LineStyle> ' +
        '<width>1.5</width> ' +
      '</LineStyle> ' +
      '<PolyStyle> ' +
        '<color>7d00ffff</color> ' +
      '</PolyStyle> ' +
    '</Style> ' +
    '<Placemark> ' +
      '<name>Building 43</name> ' +
      '<visibility>0</visibility> ' +
      '<styleUrl>#transYellowPoly</styleUrl> ' +
      '<Polygon> ' +
        '<extrude>1</extrude> ' +
        '<altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode> ' +
        '<outerBoundaryIs> ' +
          '<LinearRing> ' +
            '<coordinates> -122.0844371128284,37.42177253003091,19 ' +
              '-122.0845118855746,37.42191111542896,19 ' +
              '-122.0850470999805,37.42178755121535,19 ' +
              '-122.0850719913391,37.42143663023161,19 ' +
              '-122.084916406232,37.42137237822116,19 ' +
              '-122.0842193868167,37.42137237801626,19 ' +
              '-122.08421938659,37.42147617161496,19 ' +
              '-122.0838086419991,37.4214613409357,19 ' +
              '-122.0837899728564,37.42131306410796,19 ' +
              '-122.0832796534698,37.42129328840593,19 ' +
              '-122.0832609819207,37.42139213944298,19 ' +
              '-122.0829373621737,37.42137236399876,19 ' +
              '-122.0829062425667,37.42151569778871,19 ' +
              '-122.0828502269665,37.42176282576465,19 ' +
              '-122.0829435788635,37.42176776969635,19 ' +
              '-122.083217411188,37.42179248552686,19 ' +
              '-122.0835970430103,37.4217480074456,19 ' +
              '-122.0839455556771,37.42169364237603,19 ' +
              '-122.0840077894637,37.42176283815853,19 ' +
              '-122.084113587521,37.42174801104392,19 ' +
              '-122.0840762473784,37.42171341292375,19 ' +
              '-122.0841447047739,37.42167881534569,19 ' +
              '-122.084144704223,37.42181720660197,19 ' +
              '-122.0842503333074,37.4218170700446,19 ' +
              '-122.0844371128284,37.42177253003091,19 </coordinates> ' +
          '</LinearRing> ' +
        '</outerBoundaryIs> ' +
      '</Polygon> ' +
    '</Placemark> ' +
  '</Document> ' +
  '</kml>';

  var map = L.map('mapid').setView([37.42222, -122.08395], 14);
    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a     href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a   href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        maxZoom: 21,
        id: 'mapbox.streets',
        accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1Ijoia3J1a2FyaXVzIiwiYSI6ImNqZ2tuaHZqODAxMjYzM28yam40MmpxMmEifQ.3chgJkJajjDBxsF4YHgENA'
    }).addTo(map);

  parser = new DOMParser();
  kml = parser.parseFromString(myKML,"text/xml");
  track = new L.KML(kml);

  map.addLayer(track);
  const bounds = track.getBounds();
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

  sldOpacity.onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('image-opacity').innerHTML = this.value;
    track.setStyle({fillOpacity: this.value});
  };
</script>
</body>
```

*Remark:* If you just copy code from various sources without understanding what it does you'll be in trouble all the time.

Comment: Hi, I implemented your code, which looks correct (map looks as it was). But the layer is still opaque.
I have created in my <style> section:
#image-opacity
  {
  opacity: 0.6;
  }
  
  #sldOpacity
  {
  opacity: 0.6;
  }
regarding to this function, but it's also not correct.

I found something also here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47270647/change-opacity-using-leaflet-without-plugin

which means, that GeoJSON cannot be runned from the #sldOpacity function, although my file is .kml not geoJSON.

Comment: Syntax `#` in style means that you are defining style for specific HTML element with that id. You should have: `.image-opacity { opacity: 0.6; } .sldOpacity { opacity: 0.6; }`

Comment: Unfortunately the same problem :( layers are still opaque

Comment: I found sth here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57589514/how-to-change-opacity-of-image-imported-as-icon-in-kml-document

But it refers to google maps and I am afraid won't work in leaflet conditions

Comment: Since it worked for me, you are doing something wrong. Without seeing your code I can't guess what is wrong.

Comment: Ok I understand.
My code is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/Krukarius/3Lbmkp7n/1/

only without the KML file, because I don't know how to upload it to the fiddle

Comment: My kml file snap is available here:
https://i.imgur.com/hPEaU1X.png

Comment: In your code you refer to `#sldOpacity` and `#image-opacity` HTML element id's, but there are no such HTML elements in your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99745/discussion-between-mariusz-krukar-and-tomazicm).

Comment: Ok no worries
So what codes should I use then?
I thought, that $('#sldOpacity').on('change', function(){
$('#image-opacity').html(this.value); refers purely to the .css elements.
I was also trying to do:
$('sldOpacity').on('change', function(){
$('image-opacity').html(this.value);
removing "#", but still with no result
when I put:
</head>
<span id="image-opacity">0.6</span>
<body>
I have got my font transparent instead the image on the map
and I also don't understand the 'change' in this line:
$('sldOpacity').on('change', function(){
is it related to the html code somewhere too?

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have upvoted it because it works, but... your example refers to the KML file with polygon, whereas I am dealing with Icon linked inside the .kml file. This is why my example is not working.

Comment: I put my own .kml file instead of fetched one and it started work.
Thank you for this solution!